# Converting point data to raster layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, convert, rasterization

I have a point dataset with Eastings and Northings in meters, each point regularly spaced at 1000 m apart with a value representing mean wind speed in that km squared. I want to convert this file to a raster grid.

I don't have the necessary ArcGIS extension so how do I do it using QGIS.

Forums pointed me to the [Rasterize (Vector to Raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) function in QGIS.  However, I'm unsure what I would set the width and height to, or how this fills in the empty space between the points.

Comment: If you have a regular grid of velocity (which should be in units of distance/time, not distance squared), you shouldn't need to infill "empty space". if you want to interpolate a higher resolution, you should do so *after* converting to raster. It's only the *irregular* point pattern where you'd need to generate a TIN to produce a surface.

Comment: @BERA I entered a distance of 1000 by 1000 and it seems to have produced the raster layer I wanted which is great. I'm slightly confused however by the fact I was able to just enter 1000 and it knew which units I was referring to. I was reading about this tool in another forum and decimal degrees were the unit being used. Is the software able to detect the units of the input layer?

Comment: The units are that of the coordinate system being used. My point layer was is [epsg:3006](https://epsg.io/3006) which are in meters. If you use 4326 the units are in degrees

Answer (score 1):

Set the horizontal and vertical resolution to 1000 and size units to Georeferenced units and leave output extent empty:

[image]